# SQL: conditional statement in GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql-server, variables, operators, case, conditional-statements

I would like the below case statement to change the resultset when the variable @SubjectName is changed between 'English', 'Mathematics' and any other subject eg science.

When the variable is 'English' the column in students called Ks2en should be included in the results set, but when 'Mathematics' is selected the column changes to Ks2ma and when it is anything else Ks2av should be selected.

Where there are any blank values ('') in the results set they are replaced with 'No KS2'.

Here is what I have so far which doesn't work:

```
@SubjectName varchar(100) ='English'

SELECT CASE WHEN (student.Ks2en = '' and @SubjectName = 'English') OR 
    (student.Ks2ma = '' and @SubjectName = 'Mathematics') OR 
    (student.Ks2ma = '' AND @SubjectName <> 'Mathematics' AND
    @SubjectName <> 'English') 
            THEN 'No KS2' ELSE student.ks2en 
                OR student.Ks2ma OR student.Ks2av END AS 'KS2'
  FROM student JOIN subject 
    ON subject.upn=student.upn 
  WHERE
    [subject.Name] = @SubjectName
```

Here is an example of the student table:

```
Ks2en    Ks2ma    Ks2av
4b       3c       3a
4a       4a       4a
3c                3c
         2c       2c
4c       3a       4c
4b       4b       4b

5a       3a       4a
```

So when @SubjectName = 'English' the result set looks like:

```
Ks2    
4b       
4a       
3c
No KS2     
4c       
4b
No KS2        
5a
```

And when @SubjectName = 'Mathematics' the result set looks like:

```
KS2
3c
4a
No KS2
2c
3a
4b
No KS2 
3a
```

And when @SubjectName = 'Science' the result set looks like:

```
KS2
3a
4a
3c
2c
4c
4b
No KS2
4a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will dynamically return one of three columns depending upon subject.

Is that what you want?  You can tack you where clause at the end of the statement if needed.

John

```
-- dynamically create column
SELECT 
   CASE 
      WHEN lower(coalesce(SubjectName, 'unknown')) = 'english' THEN
        [Ks2en]
      WHEN lower(coalesce(SubjectName, 'unknown')) = 'mathematics' THEN
        [Ks2ma]
      ELSE
        [Ks2av]
   END as KS2
FROM [student] INNER JOIN [subject] ON subject.upn=student.upn 
WHERE [subject].Subjectname LIKE @SubjectName;
```

I am assuming your table schema is like the following.  I am using tuple notation.

```
student (upn, student name, ...)
subject (upn, subject name, ks2en, ks2ma, ks2av, ...)
```

If it is not, the code will not work.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. Thank you I will try your code a bit later when I'm free. In the meantime, could you explain to me what coalesce does. I've read about it, but I'm not getting it.

Comment: Hi @CRAFTYDBA I've tried your suggestion, but I get the following error: Column 'student.KS2Ma' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Does the schema have three columns named [ks2en], [ks2ma] and [ks2av]?  These have to be physical fields.

Comment: Yes. They're all in the Student table.

Comment: oh, you can not have the @SubjectName in the select clause, my bad.  Please see my updates.

Comment: Thanks @CRAFYDBA.  The schema is student (upn, ks2en, ks2ma, ks2av, ..) subject (upn, result, ...)

Comment: Actually it looks like it's working. I've had to copy the case statement into the group by clause and order by clause and I'll have to play around with the order by as it includes the left functions. Thanks mate.